# Who moved my Database property?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have the following `DbContext` code working in a project with EF 6.1.0, yet with 6.1.1 I get complaints that `Database` is not static. Any suggestions:

```
public class DataMonitorDbContext : DbContext
{
    private static readonly ImportConfig Config = ImportConfig.Read();
    static DataMonitorDbContext() {
        Database.SetInitializer<DataMonitorDbContext>(null);
    }

    public DataMonitorDbContext(string connString = null)
         : base(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connString) ? connString : ConnectionString) {

    }

    public DbSet<DataRecord> DataRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DataRecordMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LogEntryMap());
    }

    private static string ConnectionString {
        get {
            return "Data Source=" + Config.DatabasePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with a new Class Library project, EF 6.1.1 and your code inside `public class DataMonitorDbContext : DbContext`. Does `Database` refer to `System.Data.Entity.Database` when you hover over it?

Comment: When I hover over it I get an error message, but when I "Go to Declaration" it does go to `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`, not `Database`.

Comment: Can you share the entire content of the file? Or a reduced version that still has the error?

Comment: @Stijn Done. Replaced excerpt with whole class.

Comment: Odd, it still builds fine for me. Have you updated EF across all projects in your solution? Also try restarting VS and doing a clean & rebuild. Restarting VS has on multiple occasions fixed strange compiler errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the complete namespace?

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<DataMonitorDbContext>(null);
```

If that works, then you have not included the correct namespaces, or you have a namespace conflict.

Comment: Sounds probable. It would explain why VS goes to `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` when OP navigates to `Database`. The idea had entered my mind, but the question implies that nothing was changed except an update of the EF package, so I dropped it. Maybe OP omitted details.

Comment: Yes, @Stijn, it worked when I used the complete namespace. Strange days indeed.